# Print a Python array with each element to 12 decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, rounding

I have already have an **existing** **array** in Python full of numeric values. Is there a good function for me to make every element in the list appear to 12 decimal places when I print the list?

Thanks in advance!

Here is what my list looks like:
`[array([-1, -2]),
 array([ 0.93396226, -0.45283019]),
 array([2.86792453, 1.09433962]),
 array([1.86681465, 2.34572697]), ... ]`

Comment: I assume these are numpy arrays, which I haven't used. Assuming you can access the elements of an array using `for element in array_instance:`, my updated answer below should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question has been substantively edited since I answered. Old answer below.

You'll need to just add one step to the loop from the solution below:

```py
# .12 means "to twelve decimal places"
# f means format float
format_string = "{:.12f}"

# your existing list of arrays
arrays = [array(0.1466, 5.0), array(16.789, 5.67)]

# go through your list one by one
for an_array in arrays:
    # (or whatever mechanism you use to access each number in an array)
    for number in an_array:
        # format each number using the format string we created above
        print(format_string.format(number))
```

Old answer (to question "How do I print numbers from a list to 12 decimal places).

String formatting is the answer. [Here is a good rundown.](https://pyformat.info/)

```py
# .12 means "to twelve decimal places"
# f means format float
format_string = "{:.12f}"

# your existing list of numbers
numbers = [0.1466, 5.0, 16.789]

# go through your list one by one
for number in numbers:
    # format each number using the format string we created above
    print(format_string.format(number))
```

Alternatively, using the delightful f-string syntax:

```py
numbers = [0.1466, 5.0, 16.789]

for number in numbers:
    print(f"{number:.12f}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use f strings like this:

```py
a = 14.2
b = 14.123131231231231231
print(f'a = {a:.12f}')
print(f'b = {b:.12f}')
```

Output:

```
a = 14.200000000000
b = 14.123131231231
```

Comment: OP wants to print all the elements of a list. You can do that with f-strings or with formatting, but it would need to be done in a loop.

Comment: You can do the same in a loop. I was just showing a method to print variables the way OP wants.